# Is it possible to set ram start address at a value higher than 0x80000000(32 bits) in riscv bare metal?

Tags: linker-errors, riscv, bare-metal, linker-scripts

I am using a linker script to compile a program in riscv64 .I need my ram start address to be higher than 32 bits but whenever i try to modify the address in the linker script i get the following errors:

> (.text._start+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: R_RISCV_PCREL_HI20 against symbol `__global_pointer$' defined in *ABS* section in build/bm_uart_test.qemu.elf /tmp/ccU40vjX.o: in function` .L0 ':
> uart.c:(.text.uart_init+0x14): relocation truncated to fit: R_RISCV_PCREL_HI20 against `uart_base' /tmp/ccU40vjX.o: in function` uart_putc':
> uart.c:(.text.uart_putc+0xa): relocation truncated to fit: R_RISCV_PCREL_HI20 against `uart_base'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

```
The make flags are : 
AOPS = -march=rv64gc -mabi=lp64d -mcmodel=medany
COPS = -Wall -O2 -static -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -mstrict-align
CFLAGS += $(AOPS) $(COPS) -I include/
LOPTS = -lgcc -Wl,--relax,--orphan-handling=warn,--no-dynamic-linker,--gc-sections,--print-gc-sections,--strip-discarded
LOPTS_QEMU = $(LOPTS) -T bmmap.qemu.ld
CPOPS = -O binary --gap-fil 0
```

From what i understand up to this point the model medany requires that all global symbols must reside in a -+2GiB window .Since my address is higher than 32 bit ,the linker can't generate an address to reach those symbols and that's why i get the error.Is there any way to fix this ?
Please correct my assumptions if they are wrong.I would deeply appreciate any help!

Comment: it is  +-2GB relative to where you are (look at the instruction set).   we cant see your linker script (address spaces at least) so the answer should be right there where you have this gap.  The start address is specific to whomever made your core and how the implemented the address space and the startup.  Note that gcc linker realizes that it can use zero plus 2GB to address that space, so for example you can have your code much further (as far as you want) from the data if the data is in the lower 2GB gcc can access it using the zero register as an offset.

Comment: llvm's linker last time I tried (16.0.1 perhaps) did not see that trick/optimization.  Otherwise you need to keep the code and the data within 2GB (or modify the linker and/or create a large model yourself).  You can use a GOT, but I ran into an issue there and I think it may have been with static locals.  but it is a trivial experiment to confirm if it works for you.

Comment: 0x80000000 is not higher than 32 bits it is higher than 31 bits.  0x100000000 is higher than 32 bits.